# Pass data between class Component and function (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, parameter-passing

I got class Component where I'm passing data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class VisitDetails extends Component {
 //...
 render() {
 
 //...
   return() {
      <div>
         {/*pass to function EditVisit.js*/}
        <Link to={{pathname: `/visit/edit/${id}`, state: {data}}}>Edit</Link>
      <div>
   }
 }
}
```

Now I got function:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function EditVisit (data) {
  console.log(data.info)
 return(
   <div>
    Info: {data.info}
   <div>
 )
}
```

but `data.info` is no render (**undefined**).

Comment: What routing/navigation package are you using in your applicaion/code? Is `EditVisit` a react component, or really just simply a function that is invoked *somewhere*? Can you update your question to include how routing works in your app and what is rendering/invoking `EditVisit`?

Comment: I have added my imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) react hook to access route state.

Given the route

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/visit/edit/${id}`,
    state: { data },
  }}
>
  Edit
</Link>
```

EditVisit

The route state can be accessed from `location.state.data`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function EditVisit (props) {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return(
    <div>
     Info: {state.data}
    <div>
  )
}
```

## Why not use `useHistory`?

[History is mutable](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable)

> The history object is mutable. Therefore it is recommended to access
> the `location` from the render props of `<Route>`, not from
> **`history.location`**. This ensures your assumptions about React are
> correct in lifecycle hooks.

Comment: one more question: is save then to use `history.push(`/`)` ?

Comment: @4est I don't quite understand that question.

Comment: @4est If your question is about whether or not it is safe to use `history.push`, yes, that is the correct object to use for imperative navigation.

Comment: yes, I want to use for navigation, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `react-router`, I think you should use the `useHistory` hook with `location.state` to capture the state in React function component. The below is the sample code.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
function EditVisit () {
  const history = useHistory()
  const data = history.location.state
 return(
   <div>
    Info: {data.info}
   <div>
 )
}
```

You can read more at https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-pass-additional-data-while-redirecting-to-different-route-f7bf5f95d48c

Comment: when after `const data = history.location.state` I did `console.log` I see data `data: {user: "07M..3", info: "Test", VisitName: "Test2"...}` but into return id did not want to display

Comment: `{data.data.info}` and it's working, thanks for help

Comment: @Peter It is better to link official docs as they are likely to be more accurate, but even the blog you linked to doesn't use the `history` object to access route state. History is mutable and react-router-dom recommends accessing state from the `location` object, as does the blog you linked out to.

Answer (score 0):

in you case you can read it from props

```js
const EditVisit = (props) => {
  const { location: {state: { date }} } = props // date is needed variable from state
  ....
}
```

[screenshot from react-router documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tdlb.png)